# Как удалить div-ый блок по id, создаваемый динамически?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax

- На странице .jsp есть функция `setInterval(function() {` которая каждые 10сек. отправляет ajax запрос на сервер. Ответ сервера - это div-ый блок с генерируемым ID у которого есть кнопка с вызовом функции `onclick="skip(ID)"` По нажатию на кнопку "skip", полученный через ajax дивный блок должен удаляться, но я получаю следующую ошибку:

> Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.

Скрипт:

```
    function skip(x) {
    var parent = document.getElementById("turn");
    var child = document.getElementById(x);
    parent.removeChild(child);
    }
```

По сути я получаю null, то есть `document.getElementById(x);` просто не находит созданный div. В качестве параметра "x" - передаётся Integer.

Comment: Думаю вам быстрее ответят, если вы добавите полный воспроизводимый пример.

Comment: @Lukas Спасибо за ответ. Написал document.getElementById(x).remove();  и всё заработало. Вопрос не актуален. Ещё раз - спасибо.